# How to find operating system name without using WMI in VBScript?

Tags: vbscript

I need a way to find the operating system version without using winmgmts. I need a platform independent way of find the name of the OS, vista, win7, etc.

Answer (score 3):

We have to parse paths in user accounts that are different on 2K/XP then they are on Vista / Win7. The comspec return looks like this: Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]. 2k/XP is Version 5.x and Vista/Win7 is Version 6.x.

```
Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set getOSVersion = shell.exec("%comspec% /c ver")
version = getOSVersion.stdout.readall
wscript.echo version
Select Case True
   Case InStr(version, "n 5.") > 1 : GetOS = "XP"
   Case InStr(version, "n 6.") > 1 : GetOS = "Vista"
   Case Else : GetOS = "Unknown"
End Select
wscript.echo GetOS`
```

Comment: Thanks! :) I used a modified version of your case statement, but instead got the version number using a WMI object: `Set oWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")` ... and: `Set rows = oWMI.ExecQuery("Select Version from Win32_OperatingSystem",,48)`... followed by looping through the `rows` (only 1) to get the Version.

Answer (score 1):

VBscript:

```
Set oShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
os_name=oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%OS%")
WScript.Echo os_name
```

Comment: This solution returns Windows_NT for WinXP, Vista, and Win7. I need to differentiate between the various versions of NT as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
Set dtmConvertedDate = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemDateTime")
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set oss = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem")

For Each os in oss

    Wscript.Echo "Caption: " & os.Caption
    Wscript.Echo "Code Set: " & os.CodeSet
    Wscript.Echo "Country Code: " & os.CountryCode
    Wscript.Echo "Debug: " & os.Debug
    Wscript.Echo "Encryption Level: " & os.EncryptionLevel
    dtmConvertedDate.Value = os.InstallDate
    dtmInstallDate = dtmConvertedDate.GetVarDate
    Wscript.Echo "Install Date: " & dtmInstallDate 
    Wscript.Echo "Licensed Users: " & os.NumberOfLicensedUsers
    Wscript.Echo "Organization: " & os.Organization
    Wscript.Echo "OS Language: " & os.OSLanguage
    Wscript.Echo "OS Product Suite: " & os.OSProductSuite
    Wscript.Echo "OS Type: " & os.OSType
    Wscript.Echo "Primary: " & os.Primary

    Wscript.Echo "Serial Number: " & os.SerialNumber
    Wscript.Echo "Version: " & os.Version
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

From [VisualBasicScript.com](http://www.visualbasicscript.com/Short-Easy-way-to-determine-OS-m28386.aspx):

```
Option Explicit 
Dim oShell 
Dim oShellExec, oStdOutputText, sText, iElement, aOS, sOS

Set oShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell") 
Set oShellExec = oShell.Exec("%comspec% /c ver") 
Set oStdOutputText = oShellExec.StdOut 

Do While Not oStdOutputText.AtEndOfStream 
    sText = oStdOutputText.ReadLine 
    aOS = Array("Windows 95", "Windows 98", "Windows NT", "Windows 2000", "Windows XP", "Microsoft Windows [Version") 
    For iElement = LBound(aOS) To UBound(aOS) 
      If InStr(sText, aOS(iElement)) <> 0 Then 
        If aOS(iElement) = "Microsoft Windows [Version" Then 
          If InStr(sText, "Version6.0") <> 0 Then
            sOS = "Windows Vista"
          ElseIf InStr(sText, "Version 6.1")<>0 Then
            sOS = "Windows 7"
          Else
            sOS = "Windows 2003" 
          End If
        Else 
         sOS = aOS(iElement) 
        End If 
      End If 
    Next 
Loop 
WScript.Echo sOS
```

Comment: This doesn't differentiate between XP and Vista / Win7, on Win7 this returns Windows 2003

Comment: @toddstavish: Fixed to support Vista and Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

This [page](http://vbnet.mvps.org/index.html?code/system/getversionex.htm) provides several wrapper routines for obtaining general Windows operation system information, all using a single call to the GetVersionEx API.

[image: GetVersionEx: Windows Version, Service Pack and Platform Info]